# Adding "Reboot" to Startup Applications

Tags: startup, reboot, startup-applications

Since you read the title and thought, "What a terrible idea," as I have when I came up with this question, I decided to not try it myself but ask it here where somebody may have tried it once. Obviously, the first thought about adding the Reboot application to load on startup would be an infinite loop of rebooting and then the user logging in and then rebooting...

What else besides this could happen? And if it did, how would somebody go about fixing such situation? In my case, I have dual booted Linux on my Mac with macOS, I'd reboot + option key to load macOS and delete the Linux partition. Anyway, share your experience with this if you have any. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing extra will happen.

#### Revert it aback

**1. Global rules:**  to revert it back, it depends on where did you add the `reboot` statement, for example if it's a `cron` rule like:

```
@reboot reboot
```

then you can revert it back to normal by doing a `chroot` into the system with a live medium or while booting change the `init` system to a shell like `init=/bin/bash` to bypass the `cron` service.

**2. User depended:** If it's a user depended rule, then you can simply add a new user, or find the  exact file and remove it from other user account, remember you can always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> to go into another `tty` to login into `root` account (If it's enabled, you can enable it if it's not but that's an another question).

or take the user privileges for running `reboot`, you can even temporary remove exec bit of the command for anyone except the root, then login to the effected user, remove the startup lines, and fix the command permissions again.